# Django - data migrations + db dump

Tags: django, database-migration

Consider I have a DB with some initial data loaded using data migrations. Since the initial loading, the data has been further changed by users of the app via the website. Of course, these changes are not recorded in additional data migrations since they happen in realtime. So the data migrations are somewhat redundant since they don't capture all the changes made by the users.

Now, I want to deploy the app onto a new server and DB. So I take a dump of the current database, then log onto the new server and use the dump to initialize the new DB. What I'm confused about is: if I then run the aforementioned data migrations on the new DB, they will add redundant outdated data, no?

More generally, my confusion lies in how to make data migrations and db dumps work together when deploying an existing web app onto a new server+DB. Is there a better way to think about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dump will include the tables used by migrations to keep track of where the database is in terms of running your migrations. Your new database is going to be at the same place (in terms of migrations) as your current database.

Simply put, if you run

```
python manage.py migrate
```

On the new server hooked up to the new databased after you "restore" the data, it'll say there isn't anything to run.